# Using Anaconda program without Anaconda using Pycharm

Tags: python, import, pip, pycharm, anaconda

I downloaded form github a Python project, requiring conda to create the enviroment for it.
I'd like to use the project without conda, but "import" doesn't seem to work (I guess that is what conda does).
How can I do that?

Example of project folder:

> script_a.py 
>   script_b.py

scirpt_a.py:

```
def helloworld():
    print('Hello world!')
```

script_b.py:

```
import script_a

script_a.helloworld()
```

My problem is that it doesn't seems to find "script_a" even though they are in the same folder. How can I manually set that? 
I'm using pycharm for running the scripts.

Comment: Mark your project folder as Sources Root... you should be good

Comment: That is correct! Thank you for the help!

Comment: There is another problem: marking as Sources Root solves the problem of not finding other file, but still can't find import from other subfolders!

Comment: Same solution, I just needed to mark as Source Root many subfolders.